# How can I save image from camera to on my phone and retrieve it for display on a div using ionicframework

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

this is how am capturing my image

```
$scope.takePhoto = function () {

        var camera_options = { // CONFIG 1. CAMERA SETTINGS
            quality: 80,
            destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
            sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
            allowEdit: false,
            encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
            targetWidth: 100,
            targetHeight: 100,
            correctOrientation: true,
            popoverOptions: CameraPopoverOptions,
            saveToPhotoAlbum: false
        };

        $cordovaCamera.getPicture(camera_options).then(function (imageData) {

            //$scope.imgSrc = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;

            $scope.imgSrc = imageData;
            $scope.imgData = imageData;

            $scope.$apply();

        }, function (err) {

            $cordovaDialogs.alert('Picture Not Taken', 'Error', 'OK');
        });


    }
```

After that am trying to save the image to internal memory on android this way

```
 $cordovaFile.writeFile(cordova.file.externalRootDirectory, 'app/profile/' + data.id + '.jpeg', $scope.imgSrc, {'append': false}).then(function (result) {

                $cordovaDialogs.alert('Image saved', 'Success', 'OK');
            }, function (err) {
                // An error occured. Show a message to the user
                $cordovaDialogs.alert('Image not saved', 'Error', 'OK');
            });
```

The image saved can not be opened its very small 9bytes only . What am I doing wrong ?